# Can't save <connectionString> into .config file

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have an encrypted `<connectionString>` section which I'm trying to save in the .config file. While my program is running, either in debug or release mode, I can open `MyApp.vshost.exe.config` and see the encrypted section. After exiting my application, and opening it once again, the `<connectionString>` section is missing.
My application requires administrative privileges, if it makes any difference.
It's running on .NET 4.5.1. Answers in C# are welcomed.

```
Dim builder As SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder =
        New SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(conneStr.ToString)  
Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration =  
        ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
Dim section As ConnectionStringsSection =
        DirectCast(config.GetSection("connectionStrings"), ConnectionStringsSection)
Dim connSettings As ConnectionStringSettings =
        New ConnectionStringSettings("mySqlConnection",
                                      builder.ConnectionString,
                                      builder.ConnectionString)
section.ConnectionStrings.Add(connSettings)
section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider")
section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = True
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full)
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings")
```

Comment: I think you have to unprotect, then edit, then protect, then save.

Comment: @toddmo could you be more specific `about/protect` part ?

Comment: `ProtectSection`. To unprotect (decrypt conn string section), I had to use             `//decrypt connection strings
            var arguments = string.Format(@"-pd ""connectionStrings"" -app ""/{0}""", WebApplicationName);
            Shell.Run(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis", arguments, true);`